# Not able to get flow link in my viewflow application

Tags: django, django-viewflow, viewflow

I'm using viewflow engine in my django project to render the workflow in UI.On running the local server I'm not able to see the "flow" link on left bottom part of the screen which is used to see the graphical representation of workflow.Am I missing any step ? Please help .I can see all the steps of workflow written linearly on dashboard but can't find graphical view of the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Flow graph is the part of PRO package only